# $X\sim\mathcal N(0, 25)$; $Y=1$ or $-1$ with probability $1/2$ each. Define $S = XY + \frac{X}Y $ and find its distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study

> Suppose $X$ has a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $25$. Let $Y$ be an independent random variable taking values $−1$ and $1$ with equal probability. Define $S = XY + \frac{X}Y $ and $T = XY - \frac{X}Y$. Find the probability distribution of $S$ and that of $(\frac{S+T}{10})^2$.

Quite clearly, $S=2X$ or $-2X$ each with probability $1/2$, and $S+T=X$ or $-X$ each with probability $1/2$. I cannot get beyond this point. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Because $Y=1/Y$, $T=X(Y-1/Y)=X0=0$. Thus, in order to answer these two questions, you only need to find the distribution of $S=2XY$. What does this distribution look like when $Y=1$?  When $Y=-1$?  That information will reveal the distribution of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$
  S = g(X,Y)=XY + X/Y \, .
$$
The distribution of $S$ is ($B$ is a nice (Borel) set)
$$
  P(S\in B) = P(g(X,Y)\in B)
$$
[[Total Probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)]

$$
 = P(g(X,Y)\in B\mid Y = -1)P(Y=-1)+P(g(X,Y)\in B\mid Y = 1)P(Y=1)
$$
[Use the information in the conditioning event]
$$
  = P(g(X,-1)\in B\mid Y = -1)\cdot\frac{1}{2}+P(g(X,1)\in B\mid Y = 1)\cdot\frac{1}{2}
$$
[Indendence of $X$ and $Y$]
$$
  = P(g(X,-1)\in B)\cdot\frac{1}{2}+P(g(X,1)\in B)\cdot\frac{1}{2} \, .
$$
The first probability above is either zero or one, dependending on $B$. Write it with the help of an [indicator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). The second you can express easily as an integral: if $X\sim\mathrm{N}(0,25)$, then $2X$ is distributed as what? Putting everything together you have a symmetric mixture of a degenerate and a continuous distribution.